# Show that $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^{k}m,$ with $p$ prime and $(p,m)=1.$ Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p^{k}$ and $K$ a subgroup of order $p^{d}$, with $0<d\leq k$ and $K\nsubseteq H.$ We were tasked to show that $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

I've tried to prove this by contradiction. Suppose  $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then it must be noted that the order of $HK$ must divide the order of $G$ and

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}= \frac{p^km}{|HK|}\in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$

Note that $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{p^{k+d}}{|H \cap K|}$ hence

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}=\frac{m}{p^d}|H\cap K|.$$

However, gcd($p,m$)=$1$ and since $H\cap K\leq K$ (a proper subgroup, actually), then the order of $H\cap K$ divides that of $K$ but $\frac{|H\cap K|}{|K|}=\frac{|H\cap K|}{p^d}\notin \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}=\frac{m}{p^d}|H\cap K|\notin \mathbb{Z}^+$$

which is a contradiction.

I am really not that confident with my proof, so I need some feedback and hints from you guys. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you can argue more simply.

$|HK| = |H||K| / |H \cap K|$, which is a divisor of $|H||K| = p^{k+d}$. So $|HK|$ is a power of $p$.

Moreover, $H \leq HK$, so $p^k = |H| \leq |HK|$.

But $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$, and $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, so $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ that could divide $|HK|$. That is, $|HK| \leq p^k$.

The inequalities in the two previous paragraphs imply that $|H| = |HK|$. Since $H \leq HK$, this forces $H = HK$.

But then $K \leq HK = H$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hello Sir @Bungo, thank you for this. However, may I be clarified how $H$ is a subgroup of $HK$? I must have overlooked it in my reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eigenvector $H$ is always a sub**set** of $HK$, because $1 \in K$, so for any $h \in H$ we have $h = h1 \in HK$. So, if $HK$ is a subgroup, then $H$ is a sub**group** of $HK$. (For the same reason, $K$ is always a subset of $HK$, and $K$ is a subgroup of $HK$ if $HK$ is a subgroup.

Comment: I didn't realize that until you mentioned it. Thank you very much, Sir @Bungo. :)

Comment: Is this an improvement of my proof Sir, or my proof was correct and this is another way of proving the statement?

Comment: @Eigenvector I was OK with your proof until the final conclusion: how did you conclude that $\displaystyle \frac{m}{p^d}|H \cap K|$ is not an integer?

Comment: For it to be an integer, $p^d$ must either divide $m$ or $|H\cap K|$. However, we know that gcd$(p,m)$=$1$. Moreover, it must be noted that $H\cap K$ is a proper subgroup of K hence $|H\cap K| < |K|$ hence $\frac{|H\cap K|}{p^d}\notin \mathbb{Z}^+.$.

Comment: $|H\cap K|$ is just a power of $p$ less than $p^d$ since $p$ is prime, just to add. Correct me Sir if I missed something. Thank you.

Comment: @Eigenvector Looks OK! Your argument is essentially equivalent to mine, but (to me at least) it seems cleaner to state it without the fractions.

Comment: @Eigenvector Technically, "$p^d$ must either divide $m$ or $|H \cap K|$" is not true in general, you could have some of the factors of $p^d$ dividing $m$ and the others dividing $|H \cap K|$. But in your case, you can rule that out because $p$ does not divide $m$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for the insights. Well taken. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the product formula: $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$. Then $|HK|$  is a power $p^n$ of $p$ and is bigger than $|H|=p^k$. If $HK$ was a subgroup, by Lafrange, $p^k$ would divide $p^km$ and $p^{n-k}$ would divide $m$ which is not possible. QED

Comment: I think I missed something, why is $p^n$ larger than $p^k$? Thank you Sir for this.

Comment: $p^n=p^k|K|/|K\cap H|$. Since $K\not\subset H$, $|K\cap H|<|K|$, so $p^n>p^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then it must be noted that the there should exist a positive integer $a$ such that $\frac{|G|}{|HK|}$ since the order of $HK$ must divide that of $G$. Using the given above, we have

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}= \frac{p^km}{|HK|}.$$

Note that $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{p^{k+d}}{|H \cap K|}$ hence

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}=\frac{m}{p^d}|H\cap K|.$$

A necessary condition for the right hand side to be an integer is that $p^d$ should divide $|H\cap K|$ since it is given that gcd($p,m$)=$1$. However, $H\cap K\leq K$ and is a proper subgroup, actually. Hence, the order of $H\cap K$ is a power of $p$, say $p^q$, which is lesser than $p^d$. Therefore, $\frac{|H\cap K|}{|K|}=\frac{p^q}{p^d}\notin \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence

$$\frac{|G|}{|HK|}=\frac{m}{p^d}|H\cap K|\notin \mathbb{Z}^+$$

which is a contradiction. Thus, $HK$ must not be a subgroup of $G$.